# Use the output of a shell command as a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to use the output of a echo command as variable name. Like,

```
var1="test"
var2="script"
echo ${$1}
```

If `$1` is var1 echo should print test.

`${$1}` throws error "bad substitution"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called [variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (or indirect expansion). You have to use the syntax `${!var}`:

```
~$ cat s.sh
var1="test"
var2="script"
echo ${!1}
~$ ./s.sh var1
test
~$ ./s.sh var2
script
```

From `man bash`:

> `${parameter}`
>
> The value of parameter is substituted.  The braces are required when parameter is a positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter is followed by a character which is not  to  be interpreted as part of its name.
>
> If  the  first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.  This is known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions  to  this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below.  The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

Comment: The `${!prefix*}` and `${!prefix@}` expansions aren't really relevant to the goal here.

Comment: @EtanReisner Indeed… I though that, for instance, `echo ${!var1}` and `echo ${!var1*}` would both echo `test`

Comment: The `${!prefix*}` expansion expands to variable names not values. You can use those names in indirect expansions themselves though to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$ foo='bar'
$ baz='foo'
$ echo ${!baz}
bar
```